# Visual editor not showing all table rows

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor

Does anyone know why the visual editor does not show all table rows.  I have over 30 rows of data, but in the visual editor only ten are visible, the text editor is the only way to access the rest.  Is this default behavior and is there a setting for the tinymce visual editor that can be adjusted?

[image: visual editor not showing all table rows]